# Matplotlib plot one line, multiple colours, *multiple* segments

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Let's say I had some random time-series data:

```py
y = np.random.random(100) - 0.5
x = np.array(range(len(y)))
plt.plot(
    x,
    y
)
```

[image: 100 random values plotted as a line plot, all coloured blue and linked together sequentially]

What I want to do is colour some line segments one colour, and other line segments another colour. For example, maybe the ranges `0 < x < 10`,  `34 < x < 37`, and  `68 < x < 91` should all be green and everything else should be red. I can do this trivially with `plt.scatter`:

```py
plt.scatter(
    x,
    y,
    c=np.where(
        ((0 < x) & (x < 10))
        | ((34 < x) & (x < 37))
        | ((68 < x) & (x < 91)),
        'green', 'red'
    )
)
```

[image: Same random numbers as above, but now as a scatter plot and with points some points in red, other points in green]

But because this is a time series, I don't want a bunch of dots. I want one continuous line that is segmented into multiple differently coloured segments. I can't see an easy way to do this with `plt.plot`. Some sources say to do a for loop over each of the sets, and just mask out the points I want. But this does not work because it will connect all the green points into one continuous line, which is not what I want:

```py
mask = (
    ((0 < x) & (x < 10))
    | ((34 < x) & (x < 37))
    | ((68 < x) & (x < 91))
)
plt.plot(
    x[mask],
    y[mask],
    c='green'
)
plt.plot(
    x[~mask],
    y[~mask],
    c='red'
)
plt.title("WRONG - red lines are connected")
```

[image: a red and green line plot, but with the red and green lines mixing in with one another. It's wrong.][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mtFW.png)

What I want, is a short and easy way to achieve this:

```py
masks_dict = {
    'green': [
        (( 0 <= x) & (x <= 10)),
        ((34 <= x) & (x <= 37)),
        ((68 <= x) & (x <= 91))
    ],
    'red': [
        ((10 <= x) & (x <= 34)),
        ((37 <= x) & (x <= 68)),
        ((91 <= x) & (x <= 100)),
    ]
}
for color, masks in masks_dict.items():
    for mask in masks:
        plt.plot(
            x[mask],
            y[mask],
            c=color
        )
plt.title("CORRECT - all lines are joined nicely")
```

[image: a correct plot with one continuous line that's split into alternating red and green]

Also important is that the ranges `0 < x < 10`,  `34 < x < 37`, and  `68 < x < 91` are just dummy ranges, and I can't be manually typing the `masks_dict` by hand. In reality I have a time series dataset which has certain continuous sequences labelled into one of several classes, and I want one continuous line plot that is a different colour for each of the classes.

Is there an easier way to do this than the masking approach I described above?

Comment: An often-used alternative to coloring the lines, is working with a fixed line color and colored backgrounds via `plt.axhspan(0, 10, color='g', alpha=0.2)`.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want, is a short and easy way to achieve this

I don't know If it's cleaner but you can plot multiple lines at a time using the signature

```py
plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

You'll need to create the list of `args` from the `masks_dict` and call the `plt.plot()` function with it.

```py
# Create a list of (X, Y, color)
args = [[x[mask], y[mask], color]
    for color, masks in masks_dict.items()
    for mask in masks
]

plt.plot(*sum(args, []))  # flatten args and call plt.plot
```

Obviously, if you store your mask/color in a structure closer to the expected `*args`, this snippet will get much simpler.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should abstract the (relatively) messy part in a function, e.g.,

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 200, 2001)
x = np.sin(0.03141592653589793*t)
# generate intervals
np.random.seed(2023-3-6)
fences = [0.]+sorted(np.random.choice(t,12))+[200.]

def plot_seg(triple, x, y, ax=None, **plot_kws):
    color, bot, top = triple
    ax = ax if ax else plt.gca()
    valid_points = (bot<=x) & (x<=top)
    ax.plot(x[valid_points], y[valid_points], color=color, **plot_kws)

for triple in zip(['r','g','k']*5, fences, fences[1:]):
    plot_seg(triple, t, x, lw=5)
```